# Is libgdx capable of recognizing 20 - 30 fingers at the same time?

Tags: java, android, ios, touch, libgdx

I am developing a 4 players multiplayer game (some kind of multiplayer piano-like game ;) for tablets and I would liek to use libgdx framework.

However, I am not sure if it supports more than 10 fingers recognition. Ideally, I need 5 fingers/buttons for each player that can be pressed at the same time plus menu and pause button, so, let's say 20 - 25 or 30 pointers to recognize.

Is this possible with libgdx. As far as I know Android can recognize up to 256 fingers at once, but what about libgdx?

Btw. even though I am currently not developing for iOS, if somebody has the knowledge about the iPad side of 20 - 30 fingers recognition at the same time in libgdx, I am interested in that too.

Comment: "As far as I know Android can recognize up to 256 fingers at once" -- while the OS may be capable of this, hardware frequently is not. Through a `<uses-feature>` element in your manifest, you can restrict installation of your app to devices that support at least five independent touch points, to help winnow out hardware that clearly cannot handle your requirements.

Comment: I know about that, and I will restrict 4players game to only devices that support more than 20 or more touch recognition at the same time. But what about libgdx?

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple fingers is known as multitouch. LibGDX supports up to 20 fingers. You can set up a for loop to check each finger and handle their events like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++){
    int x = Gdx.input.getX(i);
    int y = Gdx.input.getY(i);
}
```

By adding the variable "i" as an argument to the gdx getX() and getY() methods, it will give you the coordinate of that specific point. You can read more about it here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html

Remember: To test multitouch, you MUST debug on an android device. You cannot use an emulator since on emulators you use your mouse to input touch and you only have one mouse cursor.

Comment: Looks like it got bumped to 40 recently: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidInput.java#L92.  It should be trivial to make this larger if you want, too.

Comment: Oh I didn't even know! Thanks, I just heard is was 20 from somewhere but it must have been old